# Как скрыть из общего меню строку `Параметры разработчика`?

Tags: android

Как включить `Режим разработчика` более менее на слуху - семь раз нажать на `Номер сборки` в `Сведениях о ПО`.

Также внутри меню `Параметры разработчика` доступно `включить/выключить`, но из общего списка настроек строка `Параметры разработчика` не скрывается.

Задался вопросом. Как скрыть из общего меню строку `Параметры разработчика`?

Comment: Странно, что не скрывается. У меня на нескольких предыдущих прошивках скрывалось по тогглу в настройках режима разработчика. Сейчас `ressurrection remix`, проверил - все работает. Может у вас баг? Правда на офф прошивках вряд ли такие баги встречаются...

Comment: Ну если само не убирпется при выключении то стоит лезть с рут правами в бд настроек и где-то там искать. Скажите версию андроида и прошивки. И есть ли рут/возможность его поставить?

Comment: @selya: не скрывается, самсунг j7, без рута

Comment: @Flippy: root-права не хотелось затрагивать

Answer (score 3):

1. Переходим в меню `Apps/Приложения`
2. Далее `Setting/Настройки`
3. Выбираем `Storage/Память`
4. `Clear Data/Очистить данные`
5. Появится диалоговое окно с предупреждением - об окончательном удалении всех данных этого приложения, а именно файлы, параметры, учетные записи, базы данных и т.д.
6. Жмем `Удалить`. Настройки параметров разработчика станут `по умолчанию`.

Чтобы включить заново, опять жмем семь раз на `Номер сборки`.

Никаких иных изменений мною не замечены. Учетные записи на месте. Вход в приложения обычный.

Надеюсь добрые люди поделятся знанием, что же конкретно хранит приложение `Setting/Настройки` в `Storage/Память`.

Answer (score 2):

В Android 7+ (может и раньше) нужно получить рут права и перейти в `/data/system/users/0/settings_global` и найти строчку `development_settings_enabled` и поменять значение на `0`.

Везде по разному, настройки могут храниться и в бд настроек. Поэтому, лучше использовать терминал:

```
settings put global development_settings_enabled 0
```

Однако этот способ выключает сами настройки разработчика, но пункт в настройках остается и нажатия на номер сборки вызывают тост "Не нужно, настройки для разработчика уже включены". Сейчас копну глубже

Итак, в исходниках андроида в классе `Settings` в методе `onStart` ставится слушатель на изменение настроек. Переменную назвали `mDevelopmentPreferencesListener`. В случве изменения вызывается метод `updateTilesList`, следом `doUpdateTilesList`. В нем ставится видимость пункту в том случае если включен
 `DevelopmentSettings.PREF_SHOW`. Помимо этого еще какая-то проверка связанная с выключенным `DISALLOW_DEBUGGING_FEATURES`.

Еще глубже...

Итак, соединил код, значение включенного пункта в настройках берется так:

```
getSharedPreferences("development", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("show")
```

Второе условие выключенного `DISALLOW_DEBUGGING_FEATURES` не изучал, но по сути это условие включенного режима дебага. Проверьте, в настройках разработчика что-то из этой темы и попробуйте выключить. Потом выключите сами настройки и вернитесь в списку пунктов, настройки разработчика должны пропасть

Напоследок, найду где хранится значение `show`.

Пока найте не могу, но это скорее всего из-за прошивки Lineage OS 14. У вас скорее всего будет такой путь

```
/data/data/com.android.development/shared_prefs/com.android.development_preference.xml
```

В этом файле будет строчка `show` со значением `true`. Меняете на `false`. Все по сути :)

Если нет рут доступа, то попробуйте перейти в Настройки>Приложения>Dev tools>Хранилище>Стереть данные и еще раз проверьте включены ли функции дебага, если нет - выключите их

Comment: очень интересно, спасибо

Comment: @Timur, не за что, самому интересны такие вещи. Советую в исходниках андроида лазить, крайне увлекательно. Кстати, получилось?